Clarification on definition: Bartle's definition of almost uniformly Cauchy sequence.
In my measure theory class, my teacher called our atention to an seemly strange definition on Bartle's The Elements of Integration and Lesbegue Measure. The definition is as follows:
Definition. A sequence $(f_n)$ of measurable functions is said to be almost uniformly convergent to a measurable function $f$ if for each $\delta > 0$ there is a set $E_{\delta}$ em $\Sigma$ with $\mu(E_{\delta}) < \delta$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $X - E_{\delta}$. The sequence $(f_n)$ is said to be an almost uniformly Cauchy sequence if for each $\delta > 0$ there is a set $E_{\delta}$ em $\Sigma$ with $\mu(E_{\delta}) < \delta$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $X - E_{\delta}$.
My question is, how these definitions aren't the same? How they differ?

The first definition is about the relation between the sequence $(f_n)$ and the function $f$, while the second definition is about a property of the sequence $(f_n)$ alone. Of course, they are closely connected, and Bartle connects them in Theorem 7.11 on the same page.

@MichaelGreinecker It seems that Lemma 7.10 stablish an equivalence between them, so I really don't see the point.

Sorry, I actually meant the lemma.
